# How to add the info-clicky structured snippet to html website? (For Google Search Results)

Tags: html, seo, google-search, google-rich-snippets

I recently noticed a new addition to Google Snippets for Structured Data search results on Google. Although I've added quite some snippets to this website, but I don't know how to enable this snippet. I'm thinking it'll either be via website or organization schema.org for the snippet to appear in the search results.

Example from [Google's Developers Page](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/):

[image: Rich Snippet Example]

Here's some excerpt code from the pages I need this info clicky to appear in search results, but I don't know how or what to modify or append to the pages. Also would `application/ld+json` script be functional for this purpose? Or is it advisable to add HTML code only?

```
<!-- LOGO -->
<div class="w-logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <div class="w-logo-h">
        <a class="w-logo-link" itemprop="url" href="index.html">
            <img class="w-logo-img" src="img/logo.png" alt="Company Name">
            <span class="w-logo-title">
            <span class="w-logo-title-h" itemprop="name">Company Name</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```